# jquery posting data attribute to the next page

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to post data stored in a data-attr to the next page, here is my code

First i add a class and data-attr to all anchor tags like this:

```
jQuery("a").addClass("wptl_link");
jQuery('a').attr('data-wptl_ip', '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>');
```

I have checked my source code when uploaded and this works fine.

I would like to add functionality to each anchor tag, to submit the data-attr of that anchor to the next page.

I am now not quite sure on what to do. I have read into .ajax and .post and not sure what the difference is?

Do i need to do something like the following:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: nextpage.php,
data: { wptl_ip: "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>"},
success: success,
dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like it should work. Did you try it?

Comment: Are you going to move to that page? because ajax sends requests behind the scene and will not take you to the page

Comment: What next page, that's an ajax call ?

Comment: nexpage.php was just an example, i will be getting the href of the anchor clicked. or will this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly, you are trying to carry some variable from page to page, when you click an anchor tag.

`$.ajax` sends the request to another page without moving to the page. `$.ajax` is used a lot for updating or getting data asynchronously, from other places. Without having to refresh the page.

You can store the data-attr in a `sessionStorage` variable.

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    var data = $(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');

    sessionStorage.setItem('wptl_ip', data);
    location.href= location;
});
```

then you can access the data info on the next page with

```
var myData = sessionStorage.getItem('wptl_ip');
```

This is assuming you want to move to the next page, along with the data.

Posting to a php file to insert in Database:

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var location = $(this).attr('href');
    var data = $(this).attr('data-wptl_ip');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'somePage.php',
        data: {someData: data} 
    }).done(function(response){
        sessionStorage.setItem('wptl_ip', data);
        location.href= location;
    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that will help me alot! How would i go about posting the data off to a mysql db upon clicking the anchor?

Comment: You can set up a `.php` page that gets `post` data, and inserts it in a DB.  Then just call the `$.ajax()` to send the data on click. here I'll append that to my answer

Comment: @danyo This is just an example of how to do it. You would still need to do the `.php` page to insert, and fix the ajax function to fit your data.

Comment: Thanks James. I will have a play with it now and let you know how i get on!

Comment: Been having a play with this, and works good! How do i go about retrieving the data on the php page? i have $ip = $_POST['data']; but this doesnt seem to output anything?

Comment: @danyo to return data to an ajax function in php, just `echo $someInfo;`.  But if you need to access a db and return results, that's a whole new question.