# How to send data attribute to php variable using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, web

This is my jquery code that takes the data attribute of a specific button having the class name ".button". I'm trying to post this data attribute to a PHP file having the name "to.php". I've also tried this with $.ajax method but in PHP it says the term is undefined when I echo $_POST['term']. Can someone help me in posting data attributes to a PHP file?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").each(function() {
    $(".button").on("click",function(){
      term = $(this).data("touserid");
      $.post("to.php",term);
    });  
  });
});
```

```php
<?php
  $to = $_POST['term'];
  echo $to;
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jquery posting data attribute to the next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842801/jquery-posting-data-attribute-to-the-next-page)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `.each`, because `$(".button").on("click")` already add handlers to all `.button`. In your case, it loops every `.button` and every time it will add handlers, to them all, on each turn.

According to [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), the `.post()` expect object or string as the second argument:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").on("click",function(){
     var touserId = $(this).attr("data-touserid");
     $.post("to.php", { term: touserId });
   }); 
});
```

If you're using `data-touserid="id"` on the button, you should use `.attr()`, because `.data('touserid')` is not the same as `.attr('data-touserid')`.

```html
<button class="button" data-touserid="touserid">send</button>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer but here I've again that message "Undefined index: term in line no.---"

Comment: Is there any other solution you have?

Comment: check the answer, hope this is helpful :)

Comment: Bro still not working. One more thing that I wanna tell you that I used  data-touserid="'.$row["Email"].'"